# ¿Cómo trabaja un atributo del tipo de la misma clase y por qué al encapsular el método se convierte en internal?

Tags: c#

Se me encargo la implementación de listas enlazadas, entonces se creo la clase "Nodo" con los siguientes atributos, entonces un nodo siempre tendrá el dato y el apuntador al siguiente nodo.

Sin embargo no sé como trabaja el atributo "**Siguiente**"; es el apuntador.

```
class Nodo
    {
        Object dato;
        Nodo siguiente;

        public object Dato { get => dato; set => dato = value; }
        internal Nodo Siguiente { get => siguiente; set => siguiente = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Significa que la clase Nodo guarda una referencia a un objeto de  su mismo tipo, como lo haría con un objeto de cualquier otro tipo. No hay nada extraño en eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una clase que tiene una referencia con ella misma se utiliza para crear **listas enlazadas**, las listas enlazadas tienen la ventaja de que pueden crecer dinámicamente, sin predefinir un tamaño, como en el caso de los arreglos que tienen un tamaño predefinido ej. **int[100]**, lo cual quiere decir que este arreglo tendrá como máximo **100** elementos, si se tratara de añadir **1** elemento más ocurriría un error, en tu caso tienes un nodo, que tiene una referencia a otra propiedad de tipo nodo, mediante esa propiedad puedes ir navegando por cada nodo siguiente hasta llegar al último:

```
nodo aux;

while(nodo != null)
{
   aux = nodo.siguiente;
   nodo = aux;
}
```

En este código vamos recorriendo la lista nodo a nodo, guardando en la **variable aux** el nodo siguiente al actual nodo y posteriormente haciendo que nodo apunte a la **variable aux**, para cuando se vuelva a ejecutar el ciclo ya nodo sea el siguiente y así sucesivamente.

Existen otras estructuras de datos que usan referencia con ellas mismas, tu caso es una lista simplemente enlazada ya que solo se puede navegar hacia adelante, pero también existen **listas doblemente enlazadas** que tienen dos referencias a ella misma para navegar hacia adelante y hacia atrás, existen también las **listas circulares** donde el último nodo apunta hacia el primero.

Existen estructuras de datos aún más complejas como son los **árboles** y los **grafos**, un ejemplo donde se usan grafos son las redes sociales, puedes investigar más en internet si lo deseas.

Answer (score -1):

Cuando tienes atributos que se llaman igual que la clase tienes dos constructores de la clase. Por tanto puedes construir Nodo de dos maneras diferentes. Cuando más de un constructor o método tienen el mismo nombre pero distintos parámetros se dice que el constructor o método está sobrecargado.

Entiendo que si usas el primer constructor tendrá un atributo que será de tipo siguienteNodo. Un tipo o estructura que deberá estar definida en algún sitio en la clase o importada y que supongo se usará para apuntar al siguiente nodo dentro de la lista enlazada. Lo normal es que sea un objeto de su mismo tipo.

Comment: ehh... de donde sacaste esto? creo que estabas pensando en otra clase... lo que muestra es simplemente un puntero a un objeto igual al contenido...

Comment: Bueno yo estoy hablando de cuanto usaba Java. Esto parece ser c# pero la filosofía creo que es la misma.

Comment: ehhh.. ahi no hay 2 constructores.. hay uno solo, y una variable publica que apunta a un objeto del mismo tipo...